# Automatically adding data to cosmos DB through ARM template

Tags: azure, automation, azure-pipelines, azure-cosmosdb, azure-rm-template

I made an ARM template which runs through an azure devops pipeline to create a new cosmos instance and put two collections inside it. I'd like to put some data inside the collections (fixed values, same every time). Everything is created in the standard way, e.g. the collections are using

```
        "type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/containers"
```

I think these are the [relevant docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.documentdb/databaseaccounts/mongodbdatabases/collections?tabs=json).

I haven't found mentions of automatically adding data much, but it's such an obviously useful thing I'm sure it will have been added. If I need to add another step to my pipeline to add data, that's an option too.

Comment: From my knowledge it is not possible to add data while deploying things. And I think it is better to let the application/service decide what data must be written. IMO the infrastructure deployment should never be the owner of or creator of the data. So maybe consider check and create you data during startup in your case?

Comment: Thanks Martin. In this case one of the collections is storing data which will change about every six-nine months, so we can safely populate it at the same time as the resource. Possibly we could store the data in a different way, but at this point that is no longer an option.

Comment: ARM deployments are meant to be idempotent. If Cosmos data were changed by deployment, that would be very risky. I think you'd need to create a separate process to seed this data, for example in a PowerShell script or other code.

Answer (score 4):

ARM templates are not able to insert data into Cosmos DB or any service with a data plane for many of the reasons listed in the comments and more.

If you need to both provision a Cosmos resource and then insert data into it you may want to consider creating another ARM template to deploy an Azure Data Factory resource and then invoke the pipeline using PowerShell to copy the data from Blob Storage into the Cosmos DB collection. Based upon the ARM doc you referenced above it sounds as though you are creating a MongoDB collection resource. ADF supports MongoDB so this should work very well.

You can find the ADF ARM template docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datafactory/factories?tabs=json) and the ADF PowerShell docs can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/?view=azps-6.0.0#data-factories). If you're new to using ARM to create ADF resources, I recommend first creating it using the Azure Portal, then export it and examine the properties you will need to drive with parameters or variables during deployment.

PS: I'm not sure why but this container resource path (below) you pointed to in your question should not used as it breaks a few things in ARM, namely, you cannot put a resource lock on it or use Azure Policy. Please use the latest api-version which as of this writing is 2021-04-15.

```
"type": "Microsoft.DocumentDb/databaseAccounts/apis/databases/containers"
```